# Laravel 5.7 - "orderBy" Not Sorting Results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

1. I have three models related through hasMany relationship: `Course`/`Lesson`/`Article` - A `Course` hasMany `Lessons` which hasMany `Articles`.
2. I have an `int` column in my `articles` table named `pos` (short for position) and I want to order the articles by it.
3. I am using the following query in my `CoursesController`, but it's not sorting the articles by this `pos` attribute:

Code:

```php
public function show(Course $course, Lesson $lessons, Article $articles)
{
    $articles = $lesson->articles()->orderBy('pos', 'asc')->get();
    return view('users.courses.show', compact('course', 'lessons', 'articles'));
}
```

**I'm using a foreach loop in blade:**

```php
@foreach($lesson->articles as $article)
   {{ $article->title }}
@endforeach
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Laravel debugbar shows the following result:**

> select * from `articles` where `slug` = 'this-is-article-one' limit 1
>       13.27ms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding.php:35
>
> select * from `articles` where `lesson_id` = 1 and `pos` < 2 order by `pos` desc limit 1 660μs\app\Http\Controllers\Users\ArticlesController.php:55
>
> select * from `articles` where `lesson_id` = 1 and `pos` > 2 order by `pos` asc limit 1 520μs \app\Http\Controllers\Users\ArticlesController.php:59
>
> select * from `courses` where `courses`.`id` = 2 limit 1 610μs view::users.articles.show:7
>
> select * from `lessons` where `lessons`.`id` = 1 limit 1 530μs
>       view::users.articles.show:8
>
> select * from `articles` where `articles`.`lesson_id` = 1 and `articles`.`lesson_id` is not null

Comment: Post your articles controller

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$lesson->articles` again in the show view, basically you make a new DB call. To get the correct values, use the variable `$articles`:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
   {{ $article->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: why not do something like this:   $lesson->load(['articles' => function($pos) { $pos->orderBy('articles.pos', 'asc'); }]);

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved!

Comment: Good to know it solves the problem!! Can you please accept it as the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using your `lesson` object in your view, use `sortBy`:

```
@foreach($lesson->articles->sortBy('pos') as $article)
   {{ $article->title }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to extend you relationship with orderBy()

```
<?php
public function articles(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Articles')->orderBy('pos','asc');
}
```